# Using Ranges and Multiplying

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

I have started creating a mini program, but I have 1 issue. I've created a variable, and I want to add something like this:

```
for x in range(0,12):
    print (rand_no) * (x)
```

The variable rand_no is defined earlier in my program, but I want to multiply it by x. Please help me.

Comment: Add the traceback for the issue you are facing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3 as your tags indicate, you need to be aware that `print` is now a function. As a result, this code doesn't do what you're expecting:

```
for x in range(12):
    # the call to `print` returns `None` and you try to multiply it by `x`
    print(rand_no) * (x)
```

Instead, you want:

```
for x in range(12):
    print(rand_no * x)
```